# Parse self-closing tags missing the '/'

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, elementtree, sgml

I'm trying to parse some old SGML code using BeautifulSoup4 and build an Element Tree with the data. It's mostly working fine, but some of the tags that should be self-closing are aren't marked as such. For example:

```
<element1>
    <element2 attr="0">
    <element3>Data</element3>
</element1>
```

When I parse the data, it ends up like:

```
<element1>
    <element2 attr="0">
        <element3>Data</element3>
    </element2>
</element1>
```

What I'd like is for it to assume that if it doesn't find a closing tag for such elements, it should treat it as self-closing tag instead of assuming that everything after it is a child and putting the closing tag as late as possible, like so:

```
<element1>
    <element2 attr="0"/>
    <element3>Data</element3>
</element1>
```

Can anyone point me to a parser that could do this, or some way to modify an existing one to act this way? I've dug through a few parsers (lxml, lxml-xml, html5lib) but I can't figure out how to get these results.

Comment: If you have the SGML DTD and if `element2` is declared as EMPTY, you might be able to use the osx SGML to XML converter. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12534420/407651.

Comment: I did stumble across that one earlier. I initially ignored it because I was hoping for a more generic solution, and also because the files I need to parse use a couple different DTDs spread out over multiple files, so I'm not too sure if it even will work.

I'll give it a shot anyway. I've exhausted all my other options unless someone gives me something else to try. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I remember now: I did try it, but I was having problems installing OpenSP.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50450793/adding-missing-xml-closing-tags-in-javascript/50457717#50457717 answering a similar question to yours, and with info on installing OpenSP

Comment: @imhotap I took a look at the post. The instructions on installing OpenSP weren't helpful, as they were directions for Linux and I'm on Windows. I did follow the link to the original SP tool and got that with no issues. It _kind of_ works, in that it parses the file, but none of the arguments I'm passing to it are doing anything. I can't even pass it a DTD file to read; it just ignores everything. So while it does parse the file, because I can't tell it which arguments should be empty, the output from it is about that same as other parsers I've tried.

Comment: @Ahndwoo If you've got SP running, just post what you did *exactly*, what you got, and what you expected instead (in a new question, preferably), and we'll be looking at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was extracting all empty elements where the end tag can be omitted from the DTD (eg. `<!ELEMENT elem_name - o EMPTY >`), creating a list from those elements, then using regex to close all the tags in the list. The resulting text is then passed to the XML parser.

Here's a boiled down version of what I'm doing:

```
import re
from lxml.html import soupparser
from lxml import etree as ET

empty_tags = ['elem1', 'elem2', 'elem3']

markup = """
<elem1 attr="some value">
<elem2/>
<elem3></elem3>
"""

for t in empty_tags:
    markup = re.sub(r'(<{0}(?:>|\s+[^>/]*))>\s*(?:</{0}>)?\n?'.format(t), r'\1/>\n', markup)

tree = soupparser.fromstring(markup)
print(ET.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True).decode("utf-8"))
```

The output should be:

```
<elem1 attr="some value"/>
<elem2/>
<elem3/>
```

(This will actually be enclosed in  tags, but the parser adds those in.)

It will leave attributes alone, and won't touch tags that are already self-closed. If the tag has a closing tag, but is empty, it will remove the closing tag and self-close the tag instead, just so it's standardized.

It's not a very generic solution but, as far as I can tell, there's no other way to do this without knowing which tags should be closed. Even OpenSP needs the DTD to know which tags it should be closing.