# How to convert SGML into XML without a DTD?

Tags: xml, sgml

I have several files of state laws in SGML format. Unfortunately, no DTD was included with the files, and the tags and structure of the document is unclear. How can I create a DTD (if necessary) and convert the SGML files to XML files? A command-line tool would be ideal.

Comment: SGML can be either HTML or XML.  DTD is not needed for XML files.  Do you have HTML or XML.  If XML you do not need to convert.  SGML can be very large and complex.  There is not standard structure because some section are optional.  Is you issue a display issue or a parsing issue?

Comment: Try [SgmlReader](https://github.com/lovettchris/SgmlReader)

Comment: @jdweng I have neither HTML nor XML. I have SGML, which both HTML and XML are derived from.

Comment: *"no DTD was included"* and *"tags and structure of the document is unclear"* - is this migration project? you might get clues if you could get your hand on whatever sgml consumer they initially have. also, what programming language you are concerned with?

Comment: @BagusTesa No, unfortunately, I am working with public files that are only available in SGML. I'm using node.js for _most_ of the rest of the project, but any way to do this works.

Comment: SGML is purely XML and doesn't need conversion according to Wiki article : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Generalized_Markup_Language.  What are you trying to do with the data.  DTD processing can be turned off,

Comment: @jdweng:  Not true.  XML is a subset of SGML.  If you re-read that Wiki SGML article and find anything that actually supports your statement, let me know and I'll correct it there too.  Thanks.

Comment: @kjhughes : Wiki clearly says : SGML was reworked in 1998 into XML, a successful profile of SGML. Full SGML is rarely found or used in new projects.  It makes no sense that XML is a subset of SGML.  Open you SGML file with a text editor and you will see at the top it is XML.

Comment: @jdweng: Click through on your quoted Wiki link on [profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profile_(engineering)) to read, *In standardization, a **profile** is a subset internal to a specification.*   There, and [later in the Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Generalized_Markup_Language#XML), it clearly and correctly states that XML is a subset of SGML.   I hope this helps with your interpretation of the Wiki page in particular and your understanding of the relationship between XML and SGML in general.

Comment: What that paragraph is saying is "W3C XML" is a subset of SGML.  SGML is still XML.  What the apps are doing is removing some of the elements in the SGML.  It looks like the OP want to remove the DTD.  It is not necessary to remove the DTD because many XML libraries have an option to DISABLE DTD processing.

Comment: SGML files can be huge and many libraries will give an Out Of Memory error with the huge files.  Best solution is to use a good library like the Net XmlReader which can handle huge XML files.

Comment: Read the Wiki Article.  The original SGML in 1986 had extra features which was not XML.  The 1996 SGML eliminated these features so 1996 SGML is fully XML.  Conversion is not necessary.

Comment: @jdweng: Your conclusion that "Conversion is not necessary" only follows from a very restricted subset of SGML and will almost never be the helpful answer to someone asking how to convert SGML to XML.  Moving on.  Good luck.

Comment: @kjhughes : Conversion is only need on very old files that are over 28 years old (before 1996).

Answer (score 2):

Once you have converted the files to XML, as suggested by @kjhughes, there are a number of tools around for DTD generation. Most IDEs such as Oxygen and XMLSpy probably have one. There's also a freestanding one that I wrote years ago and which is available at https://github.com/Saxonica/Saxon-Archive/tree/main/DTDGenerator, or on SourceForge. It works in streaming mode, because I once had to analyze a multi-gigabyte file to find out what it contained.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout https://sgmljs.net (https://www.npmjs.com/package/sgml on npmjs.com for node.js) which can be installed via `npm install -g sgml`.

The installed `sgmlproc` command-line utility does support DTD-less SGML (aka WebSGML), and can perform conversion to XML using the `-v output_format=xml` option (see the manual page at https://sgmljs.net/docs/sgmlproc-manual.html). You can also read about conversion to XML at https://sgmljs.net/docs/parsing-html-tutorial/parsing-html-tutorial.html, which is specifically about conversion of HTML to XHTML though.

It would be helpful if you could provide an example of your source SGML here. SGML needs DTD declarations for exactly those SGML features that are above and beyond the XML subset of SGML, such as tag omission, SGML/HTML-style empty elements (without end-element tags), attribute short forms, short references, and more. Depending on whether such features are used in your source SGML, you might be required to make up and add a DTD and then use `sgmlproc` or `osx`, such as in [How to parse invalid (bad / not well-formed) XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44765194/how-to-parse-invalid-bad-not-well-formed-xml/50620927#50620927) and [Adding missing XML closing tags in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50450793/adding-missing-xml-closing-tags-in-javascript).

Answer (score 1):

James Clark's [SP](http://www.jclark.com/sp/) has an SGML to XML converter, [sx](http://www.jclark.com/sp/sx.htm).

You may find a more modern converter — haven't looked — but you're unlikely to find one that's more complete and standards compliant.

Comment: That conversion is not necessary since in 1996 the latest SGML eliminated the non XML objects from the SGML specification.